# How can I deploy a hyperledger business network using docker-compose?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy a Hyperledger BNA using docker-compose. How can I do it in the cleanest way? 
    version: '2'

```
networks:
  basic:

services:
  playground:
    container_name: composer-playground
    image: hyperledger/composer-playground
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - basic
    command: composer-playground

  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    ...

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    ...

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    ...

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    ...
```

This is a `docker-compose.yml` from [This github repisitory](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.2/basic-network)
I know that I can deploy a network using this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/bnd-deploy), but as I sad. I want to deploy it using docker-compose.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Composer, be aware that 'today' Composer supports Fabric 1.1 and you are looking at Fabric 1.2 docs, and Will likely download the 'latest' Fabric 1.2 unless you specifically do something different.  (Composer support for Fabric 1.2 is coming shortly. Keep an out out for the [Release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases) for the latest information.)

There is a [Docker container for the Composer CLI](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-cli/) which will enable you to deploy your BNA.

There are [Composer tutorials](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials) on creating and deploying BNAs, but they start with the assumption that the Composer CLI is installed locally, not in a Container so you will need to adapt the approach.  The key to connecting Composer to the Fabric is the connection profile, so you will need to understand the addressing and networking aspects of your Docker environment to build the right connection profile.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. You wrote that I should adapt the approach for the docker-compose. By adapting you mean inserting the process of creating and deploying BNA into service command tag? ex:   `command: card creation && composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . && composer network install -c PeerAdmin@'$network_name' -a ./'$network_name'@'$version'.bna"`